# Unable to connect to public LDAP servers using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP servers using the PrincipalContext class provided by .NET.
I have found the following public LDAP servers for testing on this link : http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Public%20LDAP%20Servers.

Following is the code I used to connect to the LDAP service.

```
PrincipalContext dc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "directory.verisign.com");
```

The LDAP servers provided in the link are public LDAP servers and does not require authentication. Hence , we do not pass any user name or password to connect to the LDAP servers.
I managed to connect to the local Domain Controller and to another domain on our network by passing the user name and password of a user on each of these domains respectively.

When I used the above code to connect to the local domain servers using user name and password, the line executes successfully and I am able to retrieve the values as desired.
However, when I try to connect to the public LDAP servers provided in the link above, I keep getting a NullReferenceException from the code, i.e. the declaration line shown above throws the NullReferenceException.
I googled and I am unable to understand why I’m constantly getting a NullReferenceException for the public servers.
I am told that public LDAP servers do not require user name or password and hence I am assuming that the code should’ve executed flawlessly.

Could someone please explain the reason why this is happening.
Also, what is the solution to connect to those servers.

I need to connect to those servers as I need to show proof that the code can work with both secure as well as public LDAP servers.

Comment: can you give error message about it?